# Template rule is not streamable in xslt 3 - Saxon streaming

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to create variable and assign the values to an element, but the Saxon streaming is not working after this change. Please suggest me how to resolve this.

sample XML [indented for readability]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
   <jobs>
      <job>
         <location>United States</location>
         <title>Warehouse manager</title>
         <city>Buford</city>
         <state>GA</state>
         <zip>30025</zip>
         <country>United States</country>
         <job_type/>
         <posted_at>2022-03-08</posted_at>
         <job_reference>123</job_reference>
         <company>A</company>
         <mobile_friendly_apply>No</mobile_friendly_apply>
         <category/>
         <html_jobs>Yes</html_jobs>
         <url>https://google.com</url>
         <body>test</body>
         <cpa>1</cpa>
         <cpc>2</cpc>
      </job>
   </jobs>
   <generation_time>2022-03-08 18:34:07 -0500</generation_time>
   <jobs_count>466</jobs_count>
</source>
```

XSLT code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    

    <xsl:template match="source">
<xsl:variable name="feed_generation_time" select="generation_time"/>
        <Batch>
            <Header>
                
                <Field name="EmailPref" value="EmailOnlyIfErrors"/>

<xsl:element name="Field">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="name">feed_generation_time</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$feed_generation_time"/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
            </Header>           
            <xsl:for-each select="jobs/job ! copy-of(.)">
                <xsl:variable name="feed_id" select="job_reference"/>
                
                    <Job>
                        <Field name="Action" value="Add"/>
                       
                        <Field name="Country" value="US"/>
                        
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">JobTitle</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">Description</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="body"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">ApplyURL</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">City</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">State</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">PostalCode</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="zip"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">ContactCompany</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="company"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">DiscreteField1</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">ExternalClientKey</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="job_reference"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">Cpc</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="cpc"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Field">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">Cpa</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="cpa"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:variable name="NormalizedEmployeeType" select="upper-case(title)"/>
                        
                    </Job>
        
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Batch>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Template rule is not streamable\n  * Operand {generation_time} of {let $feed_generation_time := ...} selects streamed nodes in a context that allows arbitrary navigation (line 6)\n  * The result of the template rule can contain streamed nodes.

Answer (score 2):

A transformation that copies data from somewhere near the end of the source document to somewhere near the start of the result document is intrinsically non-streamable.

Can you redesign the workflow so that `generation_time` is generated at the start of the source document rather than at the end? Or even in a separate document?

If not, and assuming your real source actually does have so many jobs that you can't put them all in memory, I think that reading the source document twice is your only real option. It would involve changing your variable binding to something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="feed_generation_time" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:source-document streamable="yes" href="input.xml">
    <xsl:sequence select="string(/descendant::generation_time[1]/text())"/>
  </xsl:source-document>
</xsl:variable>
```

Martin's suggestion of using xsl:fork isn't really going to help. The effect of `xsl:fork` is that instead of holding all the input in memory for the duration of the transformation, you hold all the output in memory instead. That can solve your problem in cases where the output is much smaller than the input, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes it is a big file around 15 gb.  In my case, I am reading the file from file system and the file name is dynamic.                                                                                                ``` <xsl:variable name="feed_generation_time" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:source-document streamable="yes" href="input.xml">
    <xsl:sequence select="string(/descendant::generation_time[1]/text())"/>
  </xsl:source-document>
</xsl:variable> ``` here href value is input.xml in my case is it a file path . Is there a way i can pass the filepath to the xslt?

Comment: Yes of course, the filename can be passed as a parameter value.

Comment: @Gopinath, `<xsl:param name="file-name" as="xs:string"/>` as a global declaration, `file-name=input.xml` as a Saxon command line argument and `<xsl:source-document href="{$file-name}" ...>` to use the parameter as the href for the source document.

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of a difficult format for streaming, the `generation_time` is at the end of the `source` element, after all the `jobs/job` elements, as streaming works forwards only where you can of course throw in `copy-of` calls to materialize/buffer nodes, I don't see much way doing it as you would need to use `copy-of` on the `source` element.

Or you can try your luck and rely on `xsl:fork` e.g.

```
<xsl:fork>
  <xsl:sequence>
    <Header>
      <Field name="EmailPref" value="EmailOnlyIfErrors"/>
      <Field name="feed_generation_time" value="{generation_time}"/>
    </Header>
  </xsl:sequence>
  <xsl:sequence>
    <xsl:for-each select="jobs/job ! copy-of(.)">...</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:sequence>
</xsl:fork>
```

A different strategy would be to read the document twice, once with `xsl:source-document`, just to stream through to collect that `generation_time` at the (near) end of `source` and keep that in a variable, the second time as the main input where you then process your `jobs/job` as currently done and prefix them with the `Header` and the `feed_generation_time` from the variable.

If the `generation_time` would preceed all the `jobs/job` you could easily store it in an accumulator, but the only way to use an accumulator in your case would be to have it store all `job` data in a light weight map and then, once your template processes the `generation_time`, output that accumulator data as the XML you want. I don't know how huge your `job` data is and how well that goes, in the end you could try whether your input `jobs/job` kept in a map allow you to get by the memory problems I presume you currently have that you try to use XSLT 3 streaming.